# Is the set of points where two measurables functions are equal measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ be a measure space and $T$ be a metric space and $f,g:\Omega\rightarrow T$ be measurable functions.

Then, is the set $\{w\in \Omega:f(w)\neq g(w)\}$ measurable?

I could prove this for the case $T$ is a separable topological vector space, but I am not sure for the case when $T$ is a metric space.

**EDIT**

Let $d$ be a metric on $X$. Since $d$ is continuous, $d$ is ($\mathscr{B}_{X\times X}, \mathscr{B}_\mathbb{R}$)-measurable. Since $f,g$ are measurable, the map $F(w):=(f(w),g(w))$ is measurable with respect to $(\mathscr{F},\mathscr{B}_X\otimes \mathscr{B}_X)$.

My point is that $d\circ F$ need not be measurable. To see this, pick $A\in \mathscr{B}_\mathbb{R}$. Then, $d^{-1}(A)\in \mathscr{B}_{X\times X}$.

**If** $d^{-1}(A)\in \mathscr{B}_X \otimes \mathscr{B}_X$, then $F^{-1}(d^{-1}(A))\in \mathscr{F}$ so we are done.

**However**, $d^{-1}(A)$ need not be in $\mathscr{B}_X \otimes \mathscr{B}_X$ without the **separability condition**, because $\mathscr{B}_X \otimes \mathscr{B}_X \neq \mathscr{B}_{X\times X}$ in general.

Comment: @Yanko This is true if $f-g$ is really defined. But who knows what $T$ is, maybe we can't add elements there.

Comment: @Yanko Your argument does not work here. $f-g$ is not defined here. If you meant that to be $d(f(w),g(w))$, it does not work. (It works when $X$ is separable though)

Comment: @Yanko No, OP said he can prove it for vector spaces. He asks when $T$ is a metric space.

Comment: @Yanko I didn't say that $T$ is a vector space. I merely said that it is obvious for the case $T$ is a "separable topological vector space". And I though even though we assume that $T$ is a topological space, without the separability condition, your argument does not work.

Comment: @Rubertos why the argument with $d$ doesn't work? $d$ is continuous so $w\mapsto d(f(w),g(w))$ is measurable.

Comment: If $X$ is not separable, we cannot gurantee that $\mathscr{B}_X \otimes \mathscr{B}_X=\mathscr{B}_{X\times X}$.

Comment: @Rubertos where is it needed? do you mean that $f,g$ measurable doesn't imply that $w\mapsto (f(w),g(w))$ is measurable?

Comment: Yes, that does not imply that in general. Because the map $w\mapsto (f(w),g(w))$ is measurable with respect to $\mathscr{B}_X\otimes \mathscr{B}_X$ but the map $d$ is measurable with respect to $\mathscr{B}_{X\times X}$.

Comment: @Rubertos but $d$ is a map on $T$. I post an answer can you check it?

Comment: @Rubertos What is the sigma algebra on $T$ though? Any sigma-algebra?

Comment: @Mark Borel! ${}{}{}$

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Actually, I was not assuming the completeness. However, I am curious how could such $f,g$ can be chosen. Could you please write that as an answer?